# How to change default body color of materialize datetimepicker?

Tags: html, css, datetimepicker, materialize

You can find the entire code here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjqxOq

I am displaying a login form using Materialize CSS which you can see in the above Codepen. It has two buttons **Login** and **Register**. When Register is clicked a modal is displayed containing necessary registration fields and one of it is materialize **datetimepicker**.

Is there a possibility to change the default body color of datetimepicker?

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s6">Date of Birth
        <input type="date" class="datepicker ">
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.datepicker').pickadate({
        selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
        selectYears: 15 // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
    });
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The materializecss datepicker has a div with a class called `"picker__box"`.
If you set the background-color for this class, your datepicker will assume this color, as you can see in below codepen.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OMBoMz

```
.picker__box{
    background-color: #CCC;
}
```

**EDIT**

To change the upper half body color too, you have to set background-color for two more classes:

```
.picker__date-display, .picker__weekday-display{
    background-color: #CCC;
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. But the upper half body part still has the default color? How to change that as well.

Comment: Hey yes this worked as expected. I changed it directly in materialize.css file as I wanted datepicker to be of same color at all places. not sure if its the correct way.  Thank you again!

Answer (score 17):

I have noticed that some answers are not working
I have searched a bit and this is the result.
Change your CSS file according to this.
I have added all the text below feel free to copy.

Hope it helps...

```
.picker__date-display { background-color: #6d4e7a; }
.picker__day.picker__day--today { color: red; }
.picker__day--selected, .picker__day--selected:hover, .picker--focused .picker__day--selected { background-color: #6d4e7a;}
.picker__close { color: #6d4e7a !important;}
.picker__today { color: #6d4e7a !important;}
.clockpicker-tick:hover { background: #6d4e7a !important; }
.clockpicker-canvas line { stroke: #6d4e7a !important; }
.clockpicker-canvas-bearing { fill: #6d4e7a !important; }
.clockpicker-canvas-bg { fill: #6d4e7a !important; }
```

[image]

Comment: Sadly, although Materializecss provides some variables to set these colours (see _variables.scss) they don't provide the level of detail provided in this answer.

Comment: In version 1.0.0+, replace `clockpicker-` with `timepicker-`

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT: This doesn't change the body, but everything but the body, and let the body white**

Cant comment.

Allan Pereira solution didn't work for me, everything went to my color (even the white-background).

I used this

```
    .picker__date-display, .picker__weekday-display{
        background-color: rgba(66, 133, 244, 0.79);
    }

    div.picker__day.picker__day--infocus.picker__day--selected.picker__day--highlighted {
        background-color: rgba(66, 133, 244, 0.79);
    }

    button.picker__today, button.picker__close {
        color: rgba(66, 133, 244, 0.79);
    }
```

(color is a nice blue)

edit: codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Kgxbdj#anon-signup

Comment: I could change as required. You chould check with firebug and detect the correct element on which you are suppose to change the color code as desired.

Comment: yep this is what i did and thats why i came up with this answer :)

Comment: My friend, I posted this for the guys like me who would like a fast-working answer. Now let me invite you to actually try the accepted answer codepen and this one, http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Kgxbdj#anon-signup

Comment: Ok Alexander, i didn't get the question, my bad. I think my solution will still be great for anyone looking into this

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for me for changing the pickers color.

```
.timepicker-canvas line {
    stroke: red;
}

.timepicker-canvas-bg, 
.timepicker-canvas-bearing {
    fill: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some answers are not working but this method worked for me, just copy and paste as is in your css file.

```
.datepicker-date-display {
 background-color: rgb(118, 186, 241);
}

.datepicker-cancel, .datepicker-clear, .datepicker-today, .datepicker-done {
 color:rgb(69, 143, 204);
}

.datepicker-table td.is-today {
 color: rgb(69, 143, 204);
}

.datepicker-table td.is-selected {
 background-color: rgb(118, 186, 241);
 color: #fff;
}
```